# Combining itemize and aligned: first line to the left and remaining lines to the right

Tags: math-mode, align, itemize, mathtools, alignment

Does any know how I can combine itemize and aligned (with argument [t]) -- or another multi-line mathematical environment -- in order to obtain a multi-line equation whose first line is aligned to the left and the remaining lines are aligned to the right?

I tried to illustrate what I would like to obtain in the picture below.

[image]

My current latex-code is the following:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

$\bm{f}^{\cup}(B^1,B^2), \bm{f}^{\cap}(B^1,B^2) \in \mathcal{B}(\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2, w\cdot w^{\prime})$, respectively, where
\begin{itemize}\small
    \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
       \ell(\bm{f}^{\cup}(B^1,B^2)) = \{w^{\prime}\cdot(\mathfrak{p}-1) + \mathfrak{p}^{\prime} \colon \mathfrak{p}\in\ell(B_i),\\
\mathfrak{p}^{\prime}\in\ell(B_i)\}\text{;}
          \end{aligned}$
    \item $r(B_i^{*}) = \{w^{\prime}\cdot(\mathfrak{q}-1) + \mathfrak{q}^{\prime} \colon \mathfrak{q} \in r(B_i), \mahfrak{q}^{\prime}\in r(B_i)\}$ ;
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

which results in something like the picture below.

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: please be so kind and show us what you try so far. writing your equation from scratch is fun :-(

Comment: In your example the second line of the item strating from $\ell$ is **not** aligned to the right. Some clarification of your expectations is needeed.

Comment: I am sorry for the missing details.
I tried to explain better now.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
\ell(\mathbf{f}{^\cup (B^1,B^2)})=\lbrace w' \cdot (\mathfrak{p}-1)+\mathfrak{p}') :& \\
\mathfrak{p}\in \ell(B_i), \mathfrak{p}1\in \ell(B'_i)\rbrace;
\end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not.
I want that the second line (and the remaining lines) are aligned to the right.

Comment: So, you want the second line touching the right margin?

Comment: in this case, that is what I want. Actually, I am using a two-column template, so the right margin is really close to the left margin. Thus, to solve my problem in this template, it suffices the second line touching the right margin. 

However, in general, what I really want is that the second line follows the alignment defined by '&' until reaching the right margin. When the right margin is reached, instead of continuous going to the right, the text has to go to the left, according to the right margin.

Comment: In two-column mode, you will not have the  same  exact layout as you posted. Probably the simpler in this case is to replace the `aligned` environment with `multlined`, removing the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. Remeber `align(ed)` require   `&` to mark the alignment points. I took the opportunity to simplify a bit your code : typing `^{\prime}` isn't necessary, `'` is enough.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$\bm{f}^{\cup}(B^1,B^2), \bm{f}^{\cap}(B^1,B^2) \in \mathcal{B}(\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2, w\cdot w^{\prime})$, respectively, where
\begin{itemize}\small
    \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
       \ell(\bm{f}^{\cup}(B^1,B^2)) = \{w'\cdot(\mathfrak{p}-1) & + \mathfrak{p}' \colon \\
      & \phantom{+}\mathfrak{p}\in\ell(B_i),\mathfrak{p}'\in\ell(B_i)\}\text{;}
          \end{aligned}$
    \item $r(B_i^{*}) = \{w'\cdot(\mathfrak{q}-1) + \mathfrak{q}' \colon \mathfrak{q} \in r(B_i), \mathfrak{q}'\in r(B_i)\}$ ;
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bernard.
But this solution does not work in my case because I am using a two-column template. So, when I use '&' at beginning of the second line to define the alignment which I really want, I face a problem: the second line does not respect the right margin. Because of that I want to align the remaining lines of the equation to the right.

Comment: I was able to obtain the setting I want by using negative \hspace after '&'. But this trick seems "not elegant".

Comment: For me, it works with the`twocolumn` option. You also have the possibility to replace the `aligned` environment with `multlined`, removing the `&`.

Comment: `multlined` from `mathtools` does not push the last line to the right margin, only a little bit to right (at least in my test with `$\begin{multlined}[t]
\text{left side} \\
\text{center line}\\
\text{right side}
\end{multlined}$`).